# Best way to understand the input text before applying ngram

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk, nltk-book

Currently I am reading text from excel file and applying bigram to it. *finalList* has list used in below sample code has the list of **input words** read from input excel file.

Removed the stopwords from input with help of following library:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

bigram logic applied on list of input text of words

```
bigram=ngrams(finalList ,2)
```

input text: I completed my end-to-end process.

Current output: Completed end, end end, end process.

Desired output: completed end-to-end, end-to-end process.

That means some group of words like (end-to-end) should be considered as 1 word.

Comment: Check your tokenization?

Comment: use proper tokenizer: http://nlp.cogcomp.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you have to clean the stop words using regex. See this example:

```
 import re
 text = 'I completed my end-to-end process..:?' 
 pattern = re.compile(r"\.*:\?*") # to remove zero or more instances of such stop words, the hyphen is not included in the stop words. 
 new_text = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
 print(new_text)
 'I completed my end-to-end process'


 # Now you can generate bigrams manually.
 # 1. Tokanize the new text
 tok = new_text.split()
 print(tok) # If the size of token is huge, just print the first five ones, like this print(tok[:5])
 ['I', 'completed', 'my', 'end-to-end', 'process']

 # 2. Loop over the list and generate bigrams, store them in a var called bigrams
 bigrams = []
 for i in range(len(tok) - 1):  # -1 to avoid index error
     bigram = tok[i] + ' ' + tok[i + 1]  
     bigrams.append(bigram)


 # 3. Print your bigrams
 for bi in bigrams:
     print(bi, end = ', ')

I completed, completed my, my end-to-end, end-to-end process,
```

I hope this helps!